# Getting clang-format to format requires-expression on one line

Tags: c++, c++20, code-formatting, clang-format

Here is my code:

```cpp
if constexpr (requires { { N::uuid() } -> std::convertible_to<score::uuid_t>; })
```

clang-format (14, 15) insists in formatting it in 5 lines:

```cpp
if constexpr (requires {
                {
                  N::uuid()
                  } -> std::convertible_to<score::uuid_t>;
              })
```

which is insane, how can I ensure that it stays on one line without having to annotate every single line ?

Comment: This has been irking me as well, but unfortunately I don't think it's possible as of version 15. A minimally invasive workaround is to write all constraints as concepts, and group those in a section or file you exclude from formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with clang v18 (which is still in release candidate as of the time of writing - February 21, 2024), there will be the option [AllowShortCompoundRequirementOnASingleLine](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#allowshortcompoundrequirementonasingleline).